# Magic Mouse sideways scrolling

Tags: mouse, macos

I use a bunch of Adobe products like InDesign and Lightroom, but they are trigger happy when you use a Magic Mouse and a slight touch will send the current pages/images sideways or jump multiple images. There is a Terminal script to stop sideways scrolling which I've set and confirmed that the option is set to false in the prefs, but this makes no difference. Any other ideas on how to do this so it stops sideways scrolling? Otherwise, a good replacement mouse for graphics/photography work.

Comment: Which versions of MacOS and Adobe apps? I've used InDesign with a Magic Trackpad (and MacBook Pro trackpad) for years and not seen any problem with scrolling. What exactly was the script - can you provide a link or include it in your question?

Answer (score 4):

I've looked this up a dozen times over the last year, but just after posting found a solution that evaded me previously. This does the trick. Its in the Accessibility settings tab, not where you'd expect a solution:

https://forums.appleinsider.com/discussion/106237/is-there-any-way-to-disable-magic-mouse-scrolling-in-photoshop-illustrator

Its stopped the crazy scrolling.

Comment: Can you please specify what is the actually solution from this long thread you reference? Accessibility settings have nothing about disabling horizontal scroll for me.

Comment: I can't recall what I did at the time but I gave up on the Magic Mouse and went back to a non-Mac two button mouse with scroll wheel.

Comment: lol lol lol lol

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Scroll](https://ryanhanson.dev/scroll) app to disable horizontal scroll. You can also specify a space on the bottom half of the mouse that allows horizontal scroll, and configure horizontal scroll to be enabled/disabled based on the frontmost app (using the menu bar in the app). Disclaimer: I'm the developer and the app is not free.

[image: scroll screenshot]

Alternatively, you can use the [Multitouch](https://multitouch.app) app to disable horizontal scroll. Currently, this will disable horizontal scroll for all devices. Disclaimer: I'm the developer of the app, and the app is not free.

[image: multitouch screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't completely disable horizontal scrolling but fixed the problem for me on Google Calendar where the sensitivity was insane.

System Preferences > Accessibility > Mouse & Trackpad > mouse options > without inertia

[image: Accessibility Settings Screen shot]